# How do you hold cooked roast beef to serve pink but still warm?

Tags: roast-beef

We're going to be serving roast beef dinners to a crowd throughout the day, there will be an option for the beef of 'pink' or 'not pink'. 
We estimate needing around 5 large joints for the day. 
What's the best way to hold the joints after slow-cooking, ready for slicing, so they stay warm when served 'pink' later - without cooking them any more!
('Not pink' can obvs be cooked again when sliced)
Oven space could be a problem as we will need the ovens for roast potatoes and Yorkshire puddings however, if it can't be done without more oven space we may be able to get more.
How do restaurants do it? (quieter ones I guess - busy would be easy)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What equipment do you have available? Just what one would find in a home kitchen?

Comment: @Sneftel whose kitchen? I have a SV circulator but no blender, for example...

Comment: @Luciano The kitchen of someone who only just now joined cooking.se. :-P

Comment: how long do they need held for?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't getting reply notifications!
It's a community hall but it doesn't usually serve food, so regular domestic eqiupment plus extra if we need it.
Needs holding all day really 6 hours potentially?